# I have a Dell Chromebook with 16 gb HD and 4gb memory with Kubuntu and wish to rest Kubuntu OR put Chrome OS back on

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, format, chromebook, reinstall

Have KUbuntu on a Dell 16gb Chromebook and wish to reset Kubuntu or reinstall Chrome OS.
New to Both Kubuntu and Chrome OS, Can someone simplify a step by step to reset or reinstall KUBUNTU.  The Chrome OS was wiped and KUbuntu now resides.
Prefer a fresh Kubuntu or Chrome Install.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to *remove* Kubuntu and reinstall ChromeOS, correct? 

Comment: "Prefer a fresh Chrome Install" you need to ask chrome users how to install that. We only provide support for Ubuntu.  In theory it could be simply a factory reset. If not you would need to acquire an installation medium with chrome OS.

Comment: OK then how to reinstall fresh Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a factory reset to re-fresh the chromebook.

Press and hold **CTRL+ALT+Shift+r**, then select **Restart**, then **Powerwash**, then **Continue** and follow the instructions.

For more details, go to [the support website of google](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084?hl=en).

Comment: Yes wipe Kubuntu and reinstall Chrome OS or restore Kubuntu. Thanks